# How to get id of the element correctly?

Tags: javascript

I try to get element which id is "div", but I get an TypeofError in firefox, what's the reason?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function (){
    var oParent = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    console.log(oParent);
    var arr = oParent.getElementById('div');
    console.log(arr);
    }
</script>
<div class="test">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div id="div"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Totally unrelated but I'd recommend to use `document.querySelector('div')` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace

```
var arr = oParent.getElementById('div');
```

with

```
var arr = document.getElementById('div');
```

This because `getElementById` is a method of `document` and not of the divs.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.now I have a sense of DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you use the method "getElementById" from oParent object. But this method is available from document object.

```
var arr = document.getElementById('div');
```

Comment: that's true, maybe I need to learn more about the specification.

Comment: Because Brushan K doesn't like my previous comment :p thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are finding parent by name and it returns an array instead of single value. 
Hence your code should use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (){
      var oParent = document.getElementsByTagName('div');// this return array
      console.log(oParent);
      // loop through array and find your desired div
      for (var j=0; j<oParent.length; j++) 
      {
        if(oParent[j].id == 'div')
        {
          console.log(oParent);// here is your div
        }
      } 
    }
</script>
```

But as you are looking for `div` with `id=div` then you should find element using `getElementById`.

See below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (){
      var oParent = document.getElementById('div');// this return div with id='div'
      console.log(oParent);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Will not work because you still use "getElementById" from oParent object and not from document.

Comment: @FrédéricGRATI I have corrected my answer and checking children of parent with id="div"

Comment: although your answer help me usefully, I should advise you can improve your code style. Make it more simply! just like this, document.getElementById. Also thank you for your help.